# How to download tcpdf php class library?

Tags: php, tcpdf

How do I download tcpdf php class library for generating pdf in my web application ?

Comment: 1. https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md 2. https://packagist.org/packages/tecnickcom/tcpdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to their github page https://github.com/tecnickcom/tcpdf either download to desktop or git clone.